# write Get Method In repository pattern

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository, repository-pattern

i'm starter in Repository Pattern in EntityFreamework in Bussiness Layer

i Have Get Methods

```
public IQueryable<Contract> GetAll()
{
    var repository = new ContractsRepository(this.Context);
    return repository.GetAll();
}

public IQueryable<Contract> GetAll(Func<Contract, bool> predicate)
{
    var repository = new ContractsRepository(this.Context);
    return repository.GetAll(predicate);
}
```

These are good,But I want to do computing on the field when a function return value to do what?

For example, I have 2 tables Table 1 and Table 2

- Table1 have a Field1 and Field 2
- Table2 have Field3 and Field4.

I want the Bussiness  layer Table1 Get method to write the following

```
Field1 ,Field2,Field1+Field3,Field2+Field4
```

thanks

Comment: Erm just add the function / read only property to the Contract class...

Comment: Please select an example

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I disagree with Tony Hopkinson's comment. You *should not* add a read-only property to your `Contact` class, because such a property cannot be used in LINQ to Entities, and hence aren't suitable for methods which return `IQueryable`.

Instead, do something like:

```
    public IQueryable<ContractSumsModel> GetSums()
    {
        var repository = new ContractsRepository(this.Context);
        return from c in repository.GetAll()
               select new ContractSumsModel
               {
                   Field1 = c.Field1,
                   Field2 = c.Field2,
                   Fields1and3 = Field1 + Field3,
                   Fields2and4 = Field2 + Field4
               };
    }
```

The nice thing about this is that you can further compose the query:

```
var q = MyBusinessLayer.GetSums().OrderBy(c => c.Fields1and3).Take(5);
```

...and the whole thing is done in SQL.

Comment: They're just writable properties of `ContractSumsModel`, a type you make for that purpose.

Comment: The return value the Method is IQueryable<Contract> but value return is ContractSumsModel. Is this true??????

Comment: No, sorry. Cut and paste. I'll fix.